# Programmatically tell difference between git-svn and git repos?

Tags: svn, git, shell, git-svn, visual-c++

I've got some shell stuff set up that dynamically defines aliases depending on what sort of VC repo the CWD contains -- so, for example, 'd' runs 'svn diff' or 'git diff', depending. (Based on [this blog post](http://muness.blogspot.com/2008/06/stop-presses-bash-said-to-embrace.html), if anybody is interested...)

I'd like to define some aliases differently depending on whether I'm in a git repo versus a git-svn repo. Is there an easy way to tell the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be a bit careful when deciding which repositories exactly are git-svn repositories. A repository may contain more than one svn repository.

Kafka's solution will only work if the svn repository was cloned with the -s or --std-layout option, in which there actually *is* a branch `trunk`.

Codelogic's answer will only work if there is an svn repository called `svn` -- there's no requirement that that is true.

The easiest way to check if there *is* an svn-remote in the config is:

```
$ git config --get-regexp ^svn-remote
```

That will find any configured git-svn repository, whatever they're called. It'll exit with status 0 if there is a match, and 1 if there is no match.

But, this doesn't mean that the svn repository is really used. It might also be that someone has imported an svn repository, but uses is as a submodule or as a sub-tree merge, or even not at all. If metadata in the git-svn repository has been turned on, you can see if any svn revision has been used in the current HEAD by using something like this:

```
$ git rev-list -1 --grep='git-svn-id' HEAD
```

But that's perhaps a bit too convoluted. You decide.

Comment: thanks - the rev-list bit is too convoluted for my purposes; after poking around a bit more on my own, i'll probably just do 'if [ -d .git/svn ]' and go from there. i realize it won't handle the general case, but it covers all of mine.

thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use the output of the `git config` command to differentiate between a git and git-svn repo.

```
git config --get svn-remote.svn.url
```

should return the svn URL being synced to, if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a branch called trunk and and a branch called trunk@[REV].
However, I think codelogics approach is easier and cleaner.